# How tu get all subcategories for each video in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `subcategories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_subcategories_categories1_idx` (`categories_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subcategories_categories1` FOREIGN KEY (`categories_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=71 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brightcove_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_stillUrl` text,
  `video_thumbnailURL` text,
  `video_playsTotal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `establishments_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_videos_establishments1_idx` (`establishments_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_videos_establishments1` FOREIGN KEY (`establishments_id`) REFERENCES `establishments` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=220 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `subcategories_videos` (
  `subcategories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `videos_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subcategories_id`,`videos_id`),
  KEY `fk_subcategories_videos_subcategories1_idx` (`subcategories_id`),
  KEY `fk_subcategories_videos_videos1_idx` (`videos_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subcategories_videos_subcategories1` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategories_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subcategories_videos_videos1` FOREIGN KEY (`videos_id`) REFERENCES `videos` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I was wondering, how can I get all videos that are in determinate subcategories, for example:

```
select * from subcategories_videos where subcategories_id in(62,61);
```

here I get all videos that correspond with categories with id 62 and 61, but how can I get a video that is in both subcategories, something like this:

```
select * from subcategories_videos where videos_id=193
```

here it will get the subcategories by video id, but how can I do this for all records? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by and having

```
  select videos_id from subcategories_videos 
  where subcategories_id in(62,61)
  Group by videos_id
  Having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: You save my life my friend, I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot!